# How to route requests regionally through Amazon Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have 3 identical web servers in 3 major regions NA, EU, and Asia. The response time is crucial for this system, therefore, I want the requests to this web server to be routed to the closest instance to the request source. How do I achieve this on the DNS level using Amazon Route53?

### What I tried

1. I tried to create a `ResourceRecordSet` with its `ResourceRecords` containing all 3 IP addresses. However, I can set one `GeoLocation` per `ResourceRecordSet`.
2. I tried to create 3 `ResourceRecordSet` with their `GeoLocation.ContinentCode` set to `NA`, `EU`, and `AS` and their `ResourceRecords` set to corresponding IP addresses. However, all requests sent to the domain were routed to the same instance, regardless of the request origin.

Comment: Your requirements seem to match [Latency-based routing - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy-latency.html). This will route users via the connection with the lowest latency, which might not be the closest location geographically due to the placement of high-speed internet connections. You could then use something like [Global Latency Test - Bunny Tools](https://tools.bunny.net/latency-test) to test how it behaves.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein. This comment is super helpful. Could you also help me specify the Routing Policy as Latency based? So far, I have used `ChangeResourceRecordSets` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeResourceRecordSets.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements seem to match [Latency-based routing - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy-latency.html). This will route users via the connection with the lowest latency, which might not be the closest location geographically due to the placement of high-speed internet connections. You could then use something like [Global Latency Test - Bunny Tools](https://tools.bunny.net/latency-test) to test how it behaves.

To configure Latency-Based Routing:

- Create 3 records with the **same Record Name**
- Select a Routing Policy of **Latency**
- For each resource, select the **Region where the target is located** -- it will route based on the latency from the user requesting the DNS resolution to the selected Region
- It also wants a **Record ID** that is simply your reference for the target

You can even create these multiple records on a single page by clicking **Add Another Record** at the bottom of the screen.

To configure the Record Sets via an API call, consult the documentation for your preferred AWS SDK. For example, here is a [change_resource_record_sets - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53/client/change_resource_record_sets.html) example for boto3/Python:

```py
response = client.change_resource_record_sets(
    ChangeBatch={
        'Changes': [
            {
                'Action': 'CREATE',
                'ResourceRecordSet': {
                    'HealthCheckId': 'abcdef11-2222-3333-4444-555555fedcba',
                    'Name': 'example.com',
                    'Region': 'us-east-2',
                    'ResourceRecords': [
                        {
                            'Value': '192.0.2.44',
                        },
                    ],
                    'SetIdentifier': 'Ohio region',
                    'TTL': 60,
                    'Type': 'A',
                },
            },
            {
                'Action': 'CREATE',
                'ResourceRecordSet': {
                    'HealthCheckId': 'abcdef66-7777-8888-9999-000000fedcba',
                    'Name': 'example.com',
                    'Region': 'us-west-2',
                    'ResourceRecords': [
                        {
                            'Value': '192.0.2.45',
                        },
                    ],
                    'SetIdentifier': 'Oregon region',
                    'TTL': 60,
                    'Type': 'A',
                },
            },
        ],
        'Comment': 'EC2 instances for example.com',
    },
    HostedZoneId='Z3M3LMPEXAMPLE',
)

print(response)
```

Or, for the equivalent in the AWS CLI, see: [change-resource-record-sets — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html)

Comment: I am very grateful for the answer and I am sure this will work. I just have one problem. I do not have access to AWS console, I can only make changes through the SDK and I cannot find how to set the Routing Policy.

Comment: @M.Azyoksul - If the answer helped you upvote it. If the answer solves your problem accept it. When you have a new question, create a new post. Do not use comments to ask 
 or solve new problems. In your case, using an SDK might require a different engineer to answer or might require more space than a comment provides.

Comment: I have added examples from the documentation